# My local client not showing correct output for listunspent

Tags: listunspent

I tried using the listunspent command as follows:

```
bitcoin-cli listunspent 10 9999999 "[\"32jdC23ABv86M2ptiqMzFzCaufBtE2NCdN\"]"
```

and it shows a blank output ([]), however, when I look up the same address on Blockchaininfo.com it shows the correct outputs. What could be the problem?

The only issue I can think of is that my node is still catching up, but it is 95% done, so the data should be there.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this command only works for *addresses in my wallet*, and moreover, there is apparently no way for the reference client to do this query for addresses not in the wallet (doh :-/)

Comment: Exactly. You'll need some blockchain indexing software if you want to query arbitrary addresses.